# Django form field clean to check if entered date is in a stored range

Tags: django, validation

I'm trying to write a form clean method to ensure that an entered pair of dates is not currently covered by date ranges stored in the model.

So I want to catch `fromdate >= value <= todate` but the `between` filters in my clean methods aren't getting it.

Can anyone offer some enlightenment?

Models.py

```
class Dates(models.Model):
    fromdate = models.DateField()
    todate = models.DateField()
```

Forms.py

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    fromdate = forms.DateField()

    todate = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dates

    def clean_fromdate(self):
        form_fromdate = self.cleaned_data.get('fromdate')

        exists = Dates.objects.filter(fromdate__contains=form_fromdate).exists()
        if exists == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A period is already entered for this date"))

        between = Dates.objects.filter(fromdate__gte=form_fromdate,
            todate__lte=form_fromdate).exists()
        if between == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Period already between this date 1"))

        return form_fromdate


    def clean_todate(self):
        form_todate = self.cleaned_data.get('todate')

        exists = Dates.objects.filter(todate__contains=form_todate).exists()
        if exists == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A period is already entered for this date"))

        between = PeriodsOfInactivity2012.objects.filter(fromdate__gte=form_todate,
            todate__lte=form_todate).exists()
        if between == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Period already between this date 2"))

        return form_todate
```

Comment: Please show us Dates model. Try not to use __contains. Check if form_xdate is of datetime type.

Comment: I've posted the dates model above the forms code. The form input values are `datetime.date` objects. If I can get this between filter to work I don't need `__contains`, that is just the only one I can get working at the moment as a test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you

```
from django import forms
from models import Dates

class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    fromdate = forms.DateField()
    todate = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dates

    def clean(self):
        form_fromdate = self.cleaned_data.get('fromdate')
        form_todate = self.cleaned_data.get('todate')
        between = Dates.objects.filter(fromdate__gte=form_fromdate, todate__lte=form_todate).exists()
        if between:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Period already between this dates")
        super(Form, self).clean()
```

---

**EDIT**

```
#views.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from forms import Form

def index(request, template='index.html'):
    form = Form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse(form)

    kwvars = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render_to_response(template, kwvars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from models import Dates

class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    fromdate = forms.DateField()
    todate = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dates

    def clean(self):
        form_fromdate = self.cleaned_data.get('fromdate')
        form_todate = self.cleaned_data.get('todate')
        between = Dates.objects.filter(fromdate__gte=form_fromdate, todate__lte=form_todate).exists()
        if between:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Period already between this date 1")
        super(Form, self).clean()
```

---

```
#index.html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {%  if form.errors %}
        errors: {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry been away from work for a day. When I put this in I've started getting a NoneType error. Hopefully I can resolve that and see if the ValidationError gets raised :)

Comment: I changed it slightly so I set `cleaned_data = super(Form, self).clean()` and return cleaned_data and it works :) edited your answer to what works for me so hopefully that can help others

Comment: just editted and added complete demo-setup I used :) That's timing :D

Comment: just for the record and future readers, I think this has an issue: when editing an existent instance, ```between``` will be true (the saved instance can match) so you need to work a little more with pk on init to exclude current instance