# Setting Age Restrictions with django-user-accounts

Tags: django, authentication

I want to set an age restriction on the account Sign up Process implemented by `django-user-accounts`. I have added a field to the SignupForm like the example in the [docs](http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). In my customized view I have the following:

```
import user_accounts_custom.forms
from profiles.models import ArtistProfile, UserProfile
from datetime import date
import math

class SignupView(SignupView):

    form_class = user_accounts_custom.forms.SignupForm

    def create_user(self, form, commit=True, **kwargs):
        old_enough = self.birthday_check(form)
        if old_enough:
            return super(SignupView, self).create_user(self, form,
                 commit=True, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super(SignupView, self).create_user(self, form,
                 commit=False, **kwargs)

    def birthday_check(self, form):
        birthdate = form.cleaned_data["birthdate"]
        fraud_detect = abs(date.today() - birthdate)
        if ( (fraud_detect.days / 365.0) < 13 ):
           # WHAT ABOUT THE BABIES!!!!
           return False
       else:
           return True
```

Setting commit to False is giving me a type error further in the [create_user](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/views.py) method on the SignupView instance because it attempts to return a user object but, like I wanted, it didn't create one. I want to send an HttpResponseForbidden object or a message but I'm not sure how to implement it here given the context. The other option I am considering is using a dummy user object (specifically my Anonymous User object) and simply redirecting without creating an account; I'm not sure which path is simplest.

Comment: Django View code should only have logic concerned with displaying the view.  Form validation should be moved to your forms.py if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Everyone says skinny views and fat models but it isn't necessarily clear what the best practices are until you're in the trenches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026689/django-form-field-clean-to-check-if-entered-date-is-in-a-stored-range) helped me solve the problem, here is how I implemented it:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SignupForm, self).clean()
    bday = self.cleaned_data["birthdate"]
    fraud_detect = abs(date.today() - bday)
    if ( (fraud_detect.days / 365.0) < 13 ):
       # WHAT ABOUT THE BABIES!!!!
        raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, you cannot create an account.",
            code="too_young",
        )
    return cleaned_data
```

The trick was to intercept the `clean()` method in the `forms.py` I created to customize `django-user-accounts`.

Some additional links to help with validation (**NOTE**: these links go to `django` version 1.6):

- [Form and Field
  Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/)
- [Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/)

Comment: Yes, the answer that you went off does this correctly and separates form logic into forms.py by overriding the clean() method. cheers! Basically, any logic that has to do with a part of the app should be in the location that makes the most sense for what it is doing. Skinny views are a lot easy to read, and only output the final context for the view etc.