# Django passing user ID to filter models

Tags: python, django

I have trying to filter objects in a model to avoid people putting events in their calendars which over lap. I found the below link which helped ([Django form field clean to check if entered date is in a stored range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026689/django-form-field-clean-to-check-if-entered-date-is-in-a-stored-range)). It has left me with another issue that it blocks any other user from having an event at the same time.

My Question is, can I pass the user id number to filter the queryset? it works if I manually input my user ID number?

Code below with my last attempt?

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
    manage = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='free')
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " - " + str(self.start_time) + " - " + str(self.end_time)
```

Form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateInput
from calendar_app.models import Event
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class EventForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Event
    # datetime-local is a HTML5 input type, format to make date time show on fields
    widgets = {
      'start_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
      'end_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
    }
    fields = ['title','description','start_time','end_time']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # input_formats parses HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
    self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
    self.fields['end_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)


  def clean(self):
    form_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
    form_end_time = self.cleaned_data.get('end_time')
    form_manage = self.cleaned_data.get('manage')
    between = Event.objects.filter(manage=form_manage, start_time__gte=form_start_time, end_time__lte=form_end_time)
    if between:
      raise forms.ValidationError('Already Calendar entry for this time')
    super(EventForm,self).clean()
```

views.py

```
def event(request, event_id=None):
    instance = Event()
    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    else:
        instance = Event()
    
    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        instance.manage = request.user
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calendar_app:calendar'))
    return render(request, 'event.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `manage_id` of the `Event` object wrapped in the form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):

    # …

    def clean(self):
        form_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
        form_end_time = self.cleaned_data.get('end_time')
        between = Event.objects.filter(
            manage_id=self.instance.manage_id,
            start_time__gte=form_start_time,
            end_time__lte=form_end_time
        )
        if between.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Already Calendar entry for this time')
        super().clean()
```

of course this only works if the `Event` alreadh has a `manage_id`, but that is not a problem, since we can add the primary key of the user if necessary. It is probably also safer to filter on the `manage_id` in the `get_object_or_404` to prevent users from editing each others events:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def event(request, event_id=None):
    instance = Event()
    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id, manage_id=request.user.pk)
    else:
        instance = Event(manage_id=request.user.pk)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('calendar_app:calendar')
    else:
        form = EventForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'event.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).